# Get image from generic external finger scanner in Android

Tags: android, fingerprint

I am here because I need to know if is possible get from my scanner **Futronic-FS88** the image and then put it on a view. Actually, I sent a message to de provider requesting the **SDK** or something like that but, in another hand, I need to know if I can give support to a lot of scanners with a generic framework, library o something like that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Futronic have an SDK for Android : http://www.futronic-tech.com/product_sdk_linux.html

There's also SDK as Neurotechnology http://www.neurotechnology.com/verifinger.html which supports lot of fingerprint scanners : http://www.neurotechnology.com/cgi-bin/fingerprint-scanners.cgi?ref=vf

Comment: @JairLizcano Is it useful ?

Comment: With the futronic SDK it's just to use the SO files? I got and error that says dlopen failed: library "libpthread.so.0" not found when I load the library